# Could Economic classism cause direct economic problems independent of sociopolitics?

Tags: macroeconomics, wealth

Typically Economic classism is a point mentioned a lot in sociopolitical discourse. But, most of the discourse seemed to be about sociopolitical problems induced by economic classism occuring rather than direct problems on economy due to economic classism.

For eg Marx based his theory of the eventual transition of communism into capitalism based on it, by assuming for that economic classism is the key driver in the sociopolitical discourse.

One effect I learned which seems to be somewhat related to the topic in the question is the Cantillon effect, if we are to consider those who get "the new money" as those who become the upper class. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Cantillon)

So, suppose we were to think of economics forgetting most of the "people problems" (unrealistic assumption, I know), and try to frame economic classism in some mathematical way ignoring the effects sociopolitics and economic classism has on each other, then what could be some negative macro economics effects which could occur out of wealth hoarding?